# Is it possible to require a class in an erb template?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, erb, require

I have an erb template in which I need to use:

> CGI.unescapeHTML(someEscapedHTML)

So I need to require 'cgi', however the following fails:

```
<% require 'cgi' %>
```

With the error:

> can't dup NilClass

Comment: Fails *how*? Please be more precise in your descriptions.

Comment: @RyanBigg Updated question with Error. Please also see separate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677908/unescaping-html-string-in-rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all do not require gems or libraries in ERB please. Then CGI is required by Rails itself already.

If you want to prevent Rails 3 from auto-escaping consider using

`<%= data.html_safe %>`

instead.

Answer (score 5):

I would personally *never* put a require statement in a view, because 1) it's ugly and 2) what if another view needed that require?

A better place for this is in `config/application.rb` at the bottom, or in a file in `config/initializers`.

Comment: True enough. Just doing something quick and dirty.