# Unescaping HTML string

Tags: html, escaping

I have the inherited the following string (I can do nothing about the format):

```
 &lt;iframe \n  class=\"some_class\"\n  type=\"text/html\" \n  src=\"/embed/iframe_content.html?id=tsqA5D7_z10\" \n  width=\"960\" \n  height=\"593\" \n  marginwidth=\"0\" \n  marginheight=\"0\" \n  frameborder=\"0\"&gt;\n&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

I am rendering it in an erb template like this:

```
<%= the_string %>
```

At the moment it renders as text like this:

```
&lt;iframe  class="some_class" type="text/html" src="/embed/iframe_content.html?id=tsqA5D7_z10" width="960" height="593"  marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"&gt;&lt;/iframe&gt;
```

I need to render it as HTML.

I have tried the following:

1. `<%= the_string.html_safe %>`  # Renders the string unchanged
2. `<%= CGI.unescapeHTML(the_string) %>` # Errors with a Type Error 'can't dup NilClass'
3. `<%= CGI.unescapeHTML(the_string).html_safe %>` # Errors with a Type Error 'can't dup NilClass'
4. `<%= raw the_string %>` # Renders the string unchanged

How can I render this string as HTML?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you seem to have noticed, there are two things you need to take care of:

1. Unescaping the HTML entities
2. Printing the raw html in your view

For number 2 `<%= raw ... %>` should work fine.

For number 1 `CGI.unescapeHTML` was the right idea, but I don't think it recognizes all HTML entities so I would recommend taking a look at the [HTML Entites gem](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/)

You can also try and use the [simple_format](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-simple_format) helper method, but I think you are going to have to pass it some options for it to allow the `<iframe>` tag

also I would strongly suggest moving your `unescaping` logic into a helper method.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I will take a look.

Comment: Thanks again. The HTML Entites gem was the answer.

Answer (score 9):

what you are unescaping must not be a string and thats why you are getting Errors with a Type Error `can't dup NilClass`

Try doing
`s = String.new your_obj.to_s`

Now do

`CGI.unescapeHTML(s)`

Comment: Working in a controller? This is the right answer, but you must change to_s -> to_str.

Answer (score 4):

In the end I had to use the [HTMLEntities](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/) Gem suggested by Matthew;

1. Installed the gem with RVM and added it to my Gemfile
2. Required it in my application.rb
3. The following was the only way I could get it to render correctly. Note the extra single quotes wrapped around the_string. Without them the angle brackets don't render, though everything else does.

   > ```
   > coder = HTMLEntities.new
   > raw coder.decode("'"+the_string+"'")
   > ```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<%= raw the_string %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but has no effect on the string.

Answer (score 1):

Version 3 sounds valuable. Any reason why you are not using the_string?

`<%= raw CGI.unescapeHTML(the_string) %>`

Comment: As I mention in my question it fails with the error Type Error 'can't dup NilClass'

Comment: Sorry. You're right. But no. Same result: Type Error 'can't dup NilClass'

Comment: CGI.unescapeHTML has no issue with String, please make sure the_string.is_a?(String)