# ruby regex with quotes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I'm trying to pass more than one regex parameter for parts of a string that needs to be replaced.  Here's the string:

```
str = "stands in hall &quot;Let&#x27;s go get to first period everyone&quot; Students continue moving to seats."
```

Here is the expected string:

```
str = "stands in hall "Let's go get to first period everyone" Students continue moving to seats."
```

This is what I tried:

```
str.gsub(/&#x27;|&quot;/, "&#x27;" => "\'", "&quot;" => "\"")
```

This is what I got:

```
"stands in hall \"Let's go get to first period everyone\" Students continue moving to seats."
```

How do I get the quotes in while sending in two regex parameters using gsub?

Comment: You have forgotten the semi-colon after `&#x27` in your replacement hash.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte thanks, I get the word Let's now with the apostrophe but I still get the backslashes.  When I take out the backslash and do this `"&quot;" => """` nothing in irb renders.  I'll edit above to prevent confusion further on

Comment: Your updated version is correct. The only reason the slashes are in your final line of code is that it's an [escape sequence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences) so that you don't mistakenly think the first slash is used to terminate the string. Try setting `str1 = str.gsub(/&#x27;|&quot;/, "&#x27;" => "\'", "&quot;" => "\"")`, then do `puts str1` and you'll see that the slashes are gone.

Comment: Oh thanks @mralexlau for clarification!  I had no idea it would print out escape sequences by default but will be ignore once in a view.

Comment: No problem, the difference is that autoevaluating variables within irb (which is what I assume you're doing to execute this sample code) automatically calls the `inspect` method, which for string variables shows the string in its entirety.

Comment: @mralexlau I think you should post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I did not understand unescaping characters I found an alternative solution that might be the "rails-way"

Can you use `<%= raw 'some_html' %>`

My final solution ended up being this instead of messy regex and requiring CGI

`<%= raw evidence_score.description %>`

[Unescaping HTML string in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677908/unescaping-html-string-in-rails)

Comment: You didn't give anyone any clue that this was Rails. Next time you might want to tag it and mention it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

This is an HTML unescaping problem.

```
require 'cgi'
CGI.unescape_html(str)
```

This gives you the correct answer.

Comment: this is better solution since regex and be pretty inefficient and I would use this solution but I"m not sure how to pass  the string in from a loop that I"m running in my views that look something like this `<% @indicator_score.evidence_scores.each do |evidence_score| %>` `<%= evidence_score.description %>` in this case description is the string.  I'll try to tinker with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

**From my comments on this question:**

Your updated version is correct. The only reason the slashes are in your final line of code is that it's an [escape sequence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Strings#Escape_sequences) so that you don't mistakenly think the first slash is used to terminate the string. Try assigning your output and printing it:

```
str1 = str.gsub(/&#x27;|&quot;/, "&#x27;" => "\'", "&quot;" => "\"")
puts str1
```

and you'll see that the slashes are gone when `str1` is printed using `puts`.

The difference is that autoevaluating variables within irb (which is what I assume you're doing to execute this sample code) automatically calls the `inspect` method, which for string variables shows the string in its entirety.